# How to connect with mysql-connector-j to MariaDB 10.11 or newer?

Tags: java, mariadb, mysql-connector

I had to change some of my infrastructure so I am now using MariaDB 10.11. My problem is that my setup no longer works. My Maven setup used the mysql-connector-java 5.1.34 package to connect to an older MariaDB version without any problems. Now I get the error `unable to load authentication plugin "auth_gssapi_client"` so I updated the mysql-connector-java version to 8.3.0 with the error `java.sql.SQLException: !AuthenticationProvider.BadAuthenticationPlugin!`.

How can I get a working db connection now? Is it still possible to use the "mysql-connector-j" or do I have to use the "mariadb-connector-j" now?

Edit: Solution found, see comment

Comment: If you're using mariadb, personally I would (and do) use the mariadb-java-client artifact

Comment: If you're using MariaDB, then you should use [MariaDB Connector/J](https://mariadb.com/downloads/connectors/connectors-data-access/java8-connector).

Comment: I would like to avoid different Connectors, as the program is sometimes connected to MySQL Servers as well

Comment: MariaDB Connector/J has MySQL compatibility ("connect ... to MariaDB and MySQL databases." [ref](https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-j)). mysql-connector-j doesn't have MariaDB compatibility as a goal.

Comment: a) Do not use "root" user for connections b) If you use "root", provide a correct password. auth_gssapi_client is only used after you failed to provide correct password.

Comment: Also, if you like to avoid some connectors, avoid MySQL Connector/J . MariaDB's is better MySQL JDBC driver, for MySQL, too.

Comment: I could repair the setup. The error is misleading. There was no issue with the plugin but a typo in my config file for the user credentials. Thanks for your help